# How to optimize writing lots of data to database in WP plugin

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I'm developing a Wordpress plugin in php 7.4 that pulls data from an API and writes it into the WP database. This data is used later by the **Custom Post Types** and **Advanced Custom Fields** plugins (mentioning this just in case it's relevant) that present it to the user via different pages on a website.

The problem I'm facing is that with **big amounts of data**, the script that loads that data (called via Ajax) will just crash at some point and return a generic error, and after lots of researching and testing and talking to the hosting the only conclusion is that what's happening is that the script is running out of memory, even though we're giving it as much as we possibly can. When the script loads **smaller amounts of data**, it **works perfectly fine**, supporting the lack-of-memory theory.

Since I'd rather optimize the code than having someone pay more for hosting, I've been trying different strategies to do that, but I can't seem to find one that makes a significant impact, so I was hoping to get some ideas.

Something to know about the API and the process that's currently done when loading data: the data that's pulled every time is a refresh of pre-existing data (think a bunch of multiple records), so most of the data already exists in the database. The problem is that, because of **how the API is implemented**, there is **NO WAY** to know which data has changed and which hasn't (that's been thoroughly discussed with the API provider).

Things that I'm already doing to optimize the script:

- Compare records coming from the API to records already existing in the database, so that I only save/update the new ones (I do this via an `in_array()` comparison of the ID of the record vs the IDs of the existing records)
- Fetch from the API only the strictly necessary fields from every record
- Skip native WP functions that store data to the database whenever possible, using custom functions to directly write to database, to avoid WP performance overhead

This doesn't seem to be enough for big amounts of data. Fetching the data itself seems not to be the problem regardless of the size, it's the processing of the data and entering it into the database. So I guess I'm looking for strategies that would help optimizing the processing of big chunks of data in this situation.

**EDIT**:

Clarifying this being an AJAX script: the PHP script (the API data importer) that gets called via AJAX gets also called via CRON by a different process, and fails as well when dealing with big amounts of data.

Comment: More of than not, "out of memory" is a red herring and can't/shouldn't be resolved by throwing more memory at it.

Comment: When I build anything that uses AJAX and takes more than a second or two (or less, really), I switch to either a background task and/or a queue. The AJAX call submits the request to the queue and returns immediately. It then polls periodically to see if/when the task is complete. If you support multiple concurrent calls, the queue can return a "ticket" (just an ID) for the polling code to inquire about. For running the task, I usually prefer having a server-side cron or daemon that looks for items in the queue and processes them.